# Collision of moving large mass and small stationary mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

Hypothetically if a mass, roughly the size of earth, was accelerating at 100m/s and came in contact with a 1kg stationary mass, due to newtons 3rd law wouldn't the small mass accelerate and the large mass would accelerate in the opposite direction? I know this is incorrect but what would cause this to not be true? A thorough explanation including the role of gravity would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Think about Newton's third law in terms of conservation of momentum. $m_1 \Delta v_1 = - m_2 \Delta v_2$. The big object's change in velocity will be minuscule... Certainly it will not appear to move in the other direction (although "slows down" = "accelerates in the opposite direction)

Comment: And, 100 m/s is a speed, not acceleration

Answer (score 1):

It's first important to discuss your phrasing "was accelerating at 100 m/s." The meter-per-second is the SI unit for velocity, not for acceleration. Whether you meant (a) a constant velocity of 100 m/s or (b) an acceleration of 100 m/s/s can help me answer more specifically.

In physics, we classify two major types of collisions: elastic and inelastic. In a perfectly elastic collision, the change in kinetic energy $\Delta K$  is zero. Therefore, the particles travel away with equal speeds, but in opposite directions (in a zero-momentum frame). In a [perfectly inelastic collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision#/media/File:Inelastischer_sto%C3%9F.gif), a maximum loss of kinetic energy is observed. The classification of a collision is not only related to energy, but also momentum.

In this case, we have an inelastic collision. When the Earth-like mass collides with the 1kg mass, it will experience a force in the direction opposite to its movement, and it will slow down slightly. Therefore it loses kinetic energy, hence, we have a perfectly inelastic collision. But the force on the Earth-like mass from the 1kg mass is minimal, so the net acceleration of the Earth-like mass will be in its original direction of motion.

Another way of looking at this is via momentum. The momentum $\vec{p}$ of an object is equal to mass times velocity $m\vec{v}$. The law of conservation of momentum states that the total momentum in a system is conserved if there are no external forces involved. In this case, the Earth-like mass loses velocity, and therefore momentum, after the collision. In order to conserve momentum, the 1kg mass must have an increased momentum, and therefore it now has a velocity in the direction of the momentum vector.

The gravitational force between two objects is

$$ \vec{F_{12}} = -\frac{GM_1m_2}{r^2} \hat{r_2}$$

so the Earth-like mass and the 1kg mass do exert a gravitational force on one another. However, it is very small, and in general is irrelevant to the collision.

You could also think about it as if the Earth-like mass is sitting still and the 1kg mass is moving at 100 m/s in the other direction. Then the answer might be more obvious.